# How to execute a Spark Chain

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

When fighting in `Auto` mode, sometimes my characters will perform a `Chain` attack, but every so often they do a `Spark chain`.

What is a `Spark chain`, and how can I execute them? I assume they do more damage, than a regular chain, so mastering this would help with stronger monsters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This game has three types of Chain attack.

**Chain**
A chain is executed when your characters attack the same enemy in quick succession. Each attack must be landed sequentially within approximately 0.25s of each other.

Gives approximately 10-15% damage bonus.

**Spark Chain**
A spark chain happens when two or more characters strike the same enemy at exactly the same time.

I can't find the damage bonus for this chain, if you do, please edit.

**Element Chain**
An element chain is performed when two or more characters strike the same enemy with the same element.

Gives approximately 20-30% damage bonus.

*References,*

- [Spark chains @ Reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/4r3usy/any_thorough_explanations_of_chain_spark_chain/)
- [Tutorial guide @ Reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/3iozih/ff_brave_exvius_tutorial_guide/)

Comment: The wiki has a mechanics page with info on chains: http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Mechanics#Chain Spark chain adds +50% damage. Max boost from each type of chain is 300%, giving up to 1000% damage if you somehow have all of them max out at once (i think you could get all three at once?). In practice I don't think I've ever gotten over about 250%.